# Watson Dialog service on BlueMix: Forwarding error

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

I have created an instance for the Watson Dialog service on Bluemix. I'm authenticating to the Dialog API through a Mobilefirst Adapter using Basic authentication as specified in [IBM Watson Dialog API reference](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/dialog/api/v1/#introduction). I'm providing the username and password provided in the service credentials for the service instance in Bluemix.

When I call the adapter I get this response:

```
{
   "code": 500,
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "message": "Forwarding error",
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      "Content-Type": "application\/json",
      "Date": "Tue, 12 Jul 2016 13:41:04 GMT",
      "Server": "-",
      "Set-Cookie": "Watson-DPAT=ZRbNg044CHnee09Pm0UOAKxqVbY4fZHXWj6%2Bb4mWeYkG56h873G%2F0A1jKTBH8zWK7NJjgYtkx1SaekClhk4CoZhad0PwuORRRdwkiXhAUh03uEnEqyDWh6n0WBIVxNWOoAAoxUMAqTDxfw%2BMHtwngXyZe47TZYk7IdsvsV%2F0bhLoAF6GS8YEwaamX7b7tfqchTfoQ3%2FIF7TbktyfJ9L8tUiQrwZyLlJcWv5Typn93J1km5Jl%2Fvc4K3W7zvtVygYeurP9Bb1slAp1PRGIppn97W%2F%2F3I%2FkKq3VS0VVo5BZXhvBf7SS%2FJg5mwQ8wbTyMqjIZXqF1zKuZ5FvlLJcYX%2BvFeJG28j429rDOvpIihOn%2FmMNV9eYeAubZQ929beB32dX90B1ChNwiYMFWe9cV7ONbaUCOLpzrO6rLKFtfeonRgsp0a6wdN3KLaBWJ9A4eB%2Fjffhfgro7N3iskxjCi5jkhgY0WOGdpg4kQmbq%2F%2F3b2a0GCP6hrYn%2BJL%2BfGNYg8wcb7xLmCRN77XwP8HqCeJ6TChi8YRpheO5CVjOlP0E5QOHAYWMTxDsLe4tV34FnPYSSvxVNY9f9sALsf627ymoOcG2r03tetgsR44f9MlkFGeydbfPtAVBZidVDLzajMqcigMf9J%2B92NXGXBVypFnu4gIkb5Uee0Duf8gRcMQSJ3M%2BhbFN4UzePYh4FLXfJv5EvQOm5AJewTtJcnrsxZfiXVDdVqNDpv3c3XWN%2F5Cenc7uKtlkFuwsnusJoBOvYQXLuMuJiDT9ODHwMn8vaM9qIZy9Mo4zReKDBnZXrlwTCphLEzhTCng6X24e46C29W8SgK97AhK4H3hY%3D; path=\/dialog\/api; secure; HttpOnly",
      "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
      "X-Backside-Transport": "FAIL FAIL",
      "X-Client-IP": "195.212.29.160",
      "X-DP-Watson-Tran-ID": "gateway-dp02-2901289c-0679-40df-bdc0-db2d7ccd8847",
      "X-Error-Cause": "Zuul Error: COMMAND_EXCEPTION",
      "X-Global-Transaction-ID": "10770268"
   },
   "responseTime": 1210,
   "statusCode": 500,
   "statusReason": "Internal Server Error",
   "totalTime": 1372
```

}

Also, when trying to authenticate to the service via the command line using:

```
curl -u "username":"password" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1"
```

I get the response:

```
{"code": 500, "message": "Forwarding error"}
```

What is it happening with the service?

It is also happening to me with the other Watson service: Languaje Translator. (I haven't checked yet with the others)

Comment: I suggest to get it working without MFP first. Might very well be related.

Comment: I have also tried to access it without mobilefirst, through the command line and using curl and im not able to authenticate to the service neither. Through Mobilefirst i've been able to authenticate to other bluemix services as im doing it now so i think that is more related to the service

Comment: I have an update, I realized that when calling with curls I had to introduce the credentials as: "username":"password" instead of "{username}":"{password}". Now I'm getting the same error:  {"code": 500, "message": "Forwarding error"}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1 is not a valid endpoint. In this case `Forwarding error` is kind of like a 404.

You can use the [Watson Dialog API specification](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/dialog-v1) to see which are the valid endpoints.

For example, to get the list of dialogs you do a `GET` request to `/v1/dialogs`:

```
curl -u "username":"password" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs"
```

The output is something like:

```
{
  "dialogs": [
    {
      "name": "pizza_test_9",
      "dialog_id": "94ce77db-1d15-4438-be6f-c96be8d883a6"
    }
  ],
  "language_packs": [
    {
      "name": "en-us-legacy",
      "dialog_id": "en-us-legacy"
    },
    {
      "name": "en-us",
      "dialog_id": "en-us"
    }
  ]
}
```

Make sure you replace `username` and `password` with your service credentials.